# Sorting a structure based on a date and time element

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

I have a structure that I need to sort in ascending order:

```
typedef struct CallLogSearchDataStruct
{
    char * date;
    char * time;
    char * bParty;
    char * aParty;
    float duration;
    char * cleardownCause;
    struct CallLogSearchOutboundStruct * outboundLegs;
    int maxDataCol;
} callLogSearchDataStruct;
```

I need to sort the structure based on the date and time in ascending order. The date and time is in the following format

Date: `16/05/2011` Time: `01:20:03`

I need to sort the above two fields in ascending order, and I've been looking at qsort but I can't figure out a way of being able to do it. I am calling the function in the following way.

```
qsort(callLogSearchData, dataRow, sizeof(callLogSearchDataStruct), sortCompare);
```

And my function is as follows

```
int sortCompare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    const callLogSearchDataStruct *u1 = a;
    const callLogSearchDataStruct *u2 = b;

    if (u1->date < u2->date)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (u1->date > u2->date)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

When I do the above code, it doesn't seem to sort it and instead screws up the layout of the structure, i.e. when I export the contents of the structure to a file, everything comes out in the wrong column order, whereas it is fine, except for being in the wrong sort order if the compare is not done.

Comment: Any reason you don't store your date and time in [unix timestamp format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) ? You'll save memory and your compare function will be straightforward.

Comment: Right now, you don't compare the dates but the pointers that point to the dates.

Comment: @Michael It's mainly due to that's the format the date is required when exported to a file

Comment: @Boardy, then you can use [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/ctime/) during the export.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing pointers, which is certainly not what you are looking for. Here's one approach to compare the structs:

- Parse the strings and extract individual components like year, month day etc
- Fill a `struct tm` with required details and call `mktime` on it
- At this point you've got 2 `time_t` values which you can compare using `difftime`

This sounds like a lot of work, and it is! If you're willing to go a little non-portable you can try the wonderful [`strptime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) which converts strings to `struct tm`s.

Comment: I'll also advocate using a `yyyy/mm/dd` date format instead of `dd/mm/yyyy` , in which case `strcmp(a->date, b->date)` might be sufficient.

Comment: @nos Yes, I was thinking of mentioning `strcmp`, but then noticed the format doesn't lend itself to that. Indeed, using the format you mentioned or even converting the string to that format and then calling `strcmp` is certainly a sensible approach. Thanks for your comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are comparing character pointers and based on that you are making decisions.But you have to compare Date and Time values for sorting.
As they both are strings,you should parse strings,get year,months,date,hours,sec in different variables.
Now you can use

> mktime()

it will return  you it in time_t format.Now you can easily compare them and sort accordingly.